# How to get the video url using Jquery

Tags: jquery

We have a video player running in our html page.

The code is like below:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="http://pdk.theplatform.com/pdk/swf/flvPlayer.swf" 
        id="_playerPdkSwfObject" name="_playerPdkSwfObject"/>
```

Now we need to know which video is playing by jquery.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: you need to know the **data** parameter or the video that the swf loads?

Comment: I think we need more details...
what are you seeking? filename? video title?

Comment: $("object").prop('data')

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/pipojesi/2/edit)

`$("#_playerPdkSwfObject").prop('data')`

you should use the prop and not attr since `data` is a dom property : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('#_playerPdkSwfObject').attr('data');
```

this will returns the url in data attribute...

Answer (score 0):

console.log($("object").attr("data") gives you the name from the data attribute